# Schedule Fortnightly Build in Bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, release, bamboo, release-management, autorelease

I'm looking at automating the bamboo release in my team currently it is manually triggered. Releases happen every second Wednesday and a custom variable is set to signify this. If the variable is present an automatic merge to the release branch is triggered.

There are two issues I am running in to

- There doesn't seem to be a way to schedule a fortnightly build in bamboo.
- I don't see a way set a custom variable with a scheduled build. I just need some sort of flag to say this was the weekly build and not the automated build that happens on check in.

There are a lot of builds so I don't want to make an additional build plan for each plan.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create Schedule trigger with cron expression. Try to use expression which executes your build on 1st and 16th day of month
1 1 11 1,16 * ?

There is no way to set variable value for scheduled builds

Answer (score 0):

a)  There doesn't seem to be a way to schedule a fortnightly build in bamboo.

> You can use cron job expression for scheduling fortnightly builds.

b)    I don't see a way set a custom variable with a scheduled build. I just need some sort of flag to say this was the weekly build and not the automated build that happens on check in.

> You must be having some admin user which runs automatically triggered
>   bamboo builds. You can use Bamboo variable
>   {bamboo.ManualBuildTriggerReason.userName}. If this variable name is
>   equal to Bamboo admin user name then this build was triggered at
>   scheduled time. otherwise it was triggered by user/developer.